# Show that the conditional PMF of i.i.d. r.v.s. given a number of successes

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider n i.i.d. r.v.s. $X_{1}, ... X_{n}$,  where $X_{i}$ ~ $Bern(p)$.  Show that the conditional PMF of $(X_{1}, ... X_{n})$ given a number of successes,
$P(X_{1} = a_{1}, X_{2} = a_{2}, ..., X_{n} = a_{n} | \sum_{i=1}^n X_{i} = k),$ where $a_i \in \left\{0, 1\right\}$ is uniform.

I cannot understand the question...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.